# Backcountdown Timer creation in the alertbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, logic, countdowntimer

I  have an requirement to create a timer in that will show up in the alertbox of javascript and it will start counting back from 4 minutes to 0.. The moment  time is over , it should stop the timer. Everything I want this to be created in Javascript. I have tried with following code that I got from this link:
[Timer in Javascript](http://forum.codecall.net/topic/51639-how-to-create-a-countdown-timer-in-javascript/)

But it is not working with me. I have done this::

```
<script>
     window.onload = CreateTimer("timer", 30);
        var Timer;
        var TotalSeconds;
        function CreateTimer(TimerID, Time) {

            Timer = document.getElementById(TimerID);
            TotalSeconds = Time;
            UpdateTimer()
            window.setTimeout("Tick()", 1000);
        }

        function Tick() {
            if (TotalSeconds <= 0) {
                alert("Time's up!")
                return;
            }
            TotalSeconds -= 1;
            UpdateTimer()
            window.setTimeout("Tick()", 1000);
        }

        function UpdateTimer() {
            var Seconds = TotalSeconds;

            var Days = Math.floor(Seconds / 86400);
            Seconds -= Days * 86400;

            var Hours = Math.floor(Seconds / 3600);
            Seconds -= Hours * (3600);

            var Minutes = Math.floor(Seconds / 60);
            Seconds -= Minutes * (60);


            var TimeStr = ((Days > 0) ? Days + " days " : "") + LeadingZero(Hours) + ":" + LeadingZero(Minutes) + ":" + LeadingZero(Seconds)


            Timer.innerHTML = TimeStr;
        }


        function LeadingZero(Time) {

            return (Time < 10) ? "0" + Time : +Time;

        }
</script>


 <div class="page">


        <div id='timer' style="float: left; width: 50%; background-color: red; color: white;"></div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope, it will help you.

```
    window.onload = CreateTimer("timer", 30);
      var Timer;
      var TotalSeconds;
      function CreateTimer(TimerID, Time) { 
        Timer = document.getElementById(TimerID);
        TotalSeconds = Time;
        UpdateTimer()
        window.setTimeout(Tick, 1000); // remove double quote
      }

      function Tick() {
        if (TotalSeconds <= 0) {
        alert("Time's up!")
        return;
      }
      TotalSeconds -= 1;
      UpdateTimer()
      window.setTimeout(Tick, 1000); // remove double quote
   }

   function UpdateTimer() {
      var Seconds = TotalSeconds;

      var Days = Math.floor(Seconds / 86400);
      Seconds -= Days * 86400;

      var Hours = Math.floor(Seconds / 3600);
      Seconds -= Hours * (3600);

      var Minutes = Math.floor(Seconds / 60);
      Seconds -= Minutes * (60);


      var TimeStr = ((Days > 0) ? Days + " days " : "") + LeadingZero(Hours) + ":" +        LeadingZero(Minutes) + ":" + LeadingZero(Seconds)


      Timer.innerHTML = TimeStr;
   }


  function LeadingZero(Time) {

      return (Time < 10) ? "0" + Time : +Time;

  }
```

Comments are there where I had done changes. Also you need to modify your code as per requirement as alert message is display after every moment when seconds equal to 0 whether time is remaining. I didn't know your requirement about this I didn't touch that code.
Please follow this link for [live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/49suK/).